# Simple "Apply" function

Tags: functions

This is such a simple question its almost embarrassing, and I'm surprised I haven't figured out where I'm going wrong with this..Probably because I'm really new to the commands Function and Apply and I might be using them wrong. But anyways, here it goes:

Input:

```
Clear[g2, x];
g2 := Function[x, Apply[Log[1 + x^2] + 6 x + x^3,x]]
g2[{2, 3}]
```

Output:

```
{20 + Log[5], 45 + Log[10]}[2, 3]
```

I have the answer but whats going on with the [2,3]?? I thought I need the extra "x" because Apply takes 2 arguments..

Here is an example I am trying to follow:

Input:

```
Clear[f2];
f2 := Function[pt, Sqrt[Apply[Plus, pt^2]]]
f2[{3, 4, 12}]
```

Output:

13

Comment: Slightly off-topic, if you set a `Function`, you don't need `SetDelayed (:=)`; instead, `Set (=)` should be used. i.e. `g2 = ...` would be sufficient (and efficient too, because `f2` and `g2` are evaluated only once)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear what you are trying to do. The example you are trying to follow is not similar to your function `g2`. Since all of the functions used in `g2` are [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) there is no need to use [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html)

```
Clear[g2, x];
g2 := Function[x, Log[1 + x^2] + 6 x + x^3]
g2[{2, 3}]

(*  {20 + Log[5], 45 + Log[10]}  *)

Log[1 + #^2] + 6 # + #^3 &[{2, 3}]

(*  {20 + Log[5], 45 + Log[10]}  *)
```

If the components of `g2` weren't `Listable` you could use [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html)

```
Log[1 + #^2] + 6 # + #^3 & /@ {2, 3}

(*  {20 + Log[5], 45 + Log[10]}  *)
```

Showing that they are all equivalent

```
% == %% == %%%

(*  True  *)
```

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. Thanks for your clarification because I was obviously using Apply in an inappropriate way